# Pivoting Data in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

What is proper syntax to convert from Table Table2Dimension to Table DesiredTable in MSSQL?

[image: Sample Tables]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL Server you can get the result by using the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function:

```
select [row], [1], [2], [3]
from
(
  select [row], col, value
  from Table2Dimension
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8476/1). This gives the result:

```
| ROW | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|-----|---|---|---|
|   1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|   2 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
|   3 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select row,
       sum(case when col = 1 then value end) as [1],
       sum(case when col = 2 then value end) as [2],
       sum(case when col = 3 then value end) as [3]
from your_table
group by row
```

Comment: "Column '2Dim.value' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: @sammarcow: I updated my answer. You need to use an aggregate function on columns not in the group.

Comment: That's what I used to correct the syntax too - which requires clean data.